# Adding New Conda Env to Hydrogen for Atom

Tags: atom-editor, jupyter, hydrogen

I work with many conda environments in my workflow and like to use the hydrogen package for the Atom Editor when I am exploring objects. However I always forget how to add a new jupyter kernel to the new environments even though it is only two lines of code.

What are those lines of code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the link to the github issue where the comment is [answered](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/899).

The two lines of code to be run in your terminal are these:

```
source activate YourEnvNameHeRE
python -m ipykernel install --user --name YourEnvNameHeRE
```

After you run these two lines and restart Atom, you will now be prompted to choose which environment you use when evaluating code using Hydrogen.